# Biopython Phylo.draw() : Why not returning axes instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, biopython

There is something I don't understand in Bio.Phylo, when we do :

```
from Bio import Phylo
tree = Phylo.read("my_tree","newick")
tree_plot = Phylo.draw(tree)
```

EDIT :

```
$ cat my_tree
(((A,B),C),D)
```

tree_plot is Nonetype because Phylo.draw() doesn't return anything.
The 2 last lines of the [source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Phylo/_utils.py) are :

```
    if do_show:
        plt.show()
```

I would like to interact with the tree, and add for instance a dot in front of some of the tree leaves.
So I added in the source code on my computer at the last line :

```
    if do_show:
        plt.show()
    return axes
```

now, with the piece of code I write at the beginning, I have in tree_plot:

```
In [1]: type(tree_plot)
Out[1]: matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot
```

And I'm now able to access data from the tree with for instance :

```
In [2]: tree_plot.texts
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x114d02710>,
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x114d02990>,
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x114d02ed0>,
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x114d00cd0>,
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x114d3c410>,
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x114d3cb10>]
```

or plotting a line with :

```
tree_plot.plot(range(10))
```

And so on with any other axes.AxesSubplot method.

### My question is :

Why is there no `return` statement in the `Phylo.draw()` function ? If it's on purpose, why and how one can draw something on the same axis ?

I'm using

- python 2.7.3
- matplotlib 1.3.0
- Biopython 1.63

Thanks

Comment: How about this `Phylo.plt.gca()`?

Comment: Do you have an example tree you can supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why they don't return the figure you will have to ask the developers (or maybe suggest the change). However it is quite easy to work around:

First make sure you have `matplotlib` in interactive mode:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

Then run your:

```
Phylo.draw(tree)
```

After that if you just want the `ax`, to add some text you use

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.text(1, 4, "Hello World")
plt.show()
```

Or if you want the whole figure use `plt.gcf()`. Remember to do `plt.show()` to see your updates.